# Android startActivity base launcher

Tags: android, activity, launcher

Использую приложение как LAUNCHER установив в манифесте

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_MODE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
    <category android:name="RUN_AT_BOOT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Но хочу дать возможность выйти в базовый лаунчер операционки, поблуждав по недрам интернета нашел такой вот вызов перехода

```
val launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.launcher")
launchIntent?.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(launchIntent)
```

где "com.android.launcher" - то что мне вернул проверочный код, который я так же нашел в сети

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
val resolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
val currentHomePackage = resolveInfo!!.activityInfo.packageName
Log.d("currentHomePackage", currentHomePackage)
```

Но как я понимаю тот же "com.android.launcher" возвращает именно установленный как HOME класс активности. Может кто подскажет как вызвать тот самый, родной лаунчер по запросу?

Answer (score 1):

Всё несколько сложнее.
`com.android.launcher` - это launcher AOSP, но на устройстве "родным" он может и не быть.   Производители аппаратов предустанавливают собственные оболочки, юзеры в свою очередь ставят сторонние.
**Итого:** вам нужно как-то узнать кто был дефолтным до вас (не представляю как это сделать), либо дать юзеру выбрать из списка всех, что есть в системе:

```java
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Title for chooser"));
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#AppChooser).

Если же вы хотите ещё и снять умолчание со своего приложения:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#clearPackagePreferredActivities(java.lang.String)

Когда умолчание снято, то при запуске интента `MAIN/HOME` или нажатии кнопки home будет предложен выбор.