# Android intent-filter включить/отключить category HOME

Tags: android, activity, launcher

Есть приложение перекрывающее рабочий стол

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_MODE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
                <category android:name="RUN_AT_BOOT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Стоит задача дать возможность пользователю закрывать приложение "секретной" кнопкой. Пробовал реализовать через activity-alias, но при переключении приложение крешится, и восстанавливается как только что установленное. Может есть у кого опыт, поделитесь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под закрытием? Для обычного приложения это возвращение в предыдущую активность и в корне стека находится домашний экран, который не больше не меньше чем активити стокового лончера. Если вы заменили его своим приложением, то выходить вам некуда. Вы можете только запустить тот самый лончер принудительно.

Comment: Хмм... собственно я вам уже отвечал на подобный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1207346/11515 - из ответа вам ничего не пригодилось?

Comment: @woesss, спасибо за ответ, но это не то что я хочу получить. Идея другая, при условной активации некой настройки получить возможность выходить на стандартный лаунчер нажатием кнопки HOME (та что по центру).

Comment: Так именно об этом и ответ - направления, по которым нужно работать даны. Или объясните подробнее какого именно поведения вы добиваетесь. Ну активировали настройку - и... Ваше приложение должно перестать быть лончером по-умолчанию вообще? Или "стандартный" лончер должен запуститься только из вашего приложения и никакого другого?

Comment: Мое приложение по умолчанию является лаунчером, но хочу иметь возможность сделать его не лаунчером, если пользователь этого пожелает.

Comment: Вы пробовали это [packageManager.clearPackagePreferredActivities("your.package.name")](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#clearPackagePreferredActivities(java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: @woesss , пробовал, приложение перезапускается, логи чистые. Использовал примеры из первых страниц гугла. Натыкался на него и ранее. Но думаю что причина в статусе деприкейтед. Студия ругается на пермишен

Comment: Вариант с выключением/включением активности тоже не работает? На худой конец можно открыть юзеру окно системных настроек, где можно снять умолчание. Ну и раз уж вы что-то пробовали - стоит перечислить в вопросе что именно, чтобы не тратить даром время на повторение одного и того же.

Comment: @woesss "На худой конец можно открыть юзеру окно системных настроек" - А можно про это вот подробнее?)

Comment: В классе `android.provider.Settings` перечислен набор экшенов для открытия разных окон настроек. Предположительно вам нужен [`ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS), но *Added in API level 21*. Для версий постарше можно подобрать что-то наиболее подходящее, например, окно настроек своего приложения (`ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`). Я не делал подобного - не могу сказать что лучше подойдёт для задачи.